# What does the vertical bar mean in Flask Templates?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I am working on a [flask tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms), and in the sample code, it contains the following:

```
| {% for pr in providers %}
    <a href ="javascript:set_openid('{{ pr.url}}', '{{ pr.name }}');">{{ pr.name }}</a> |
{% endfor %}
```

In this context, what do the vertical bars mean?

Comment: They are vertical bars. Displayed in the webpage. You can clearly see them in the screenshot on that page you linked

Comment: @UnholySheep Right, and I also saw them on the page I was building along side the tutorial. It was just difficult for me to make that connection for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
| {% for pr in providers %}
    <a href ="javascript:set_openid('{{ pr.url}}', '{{ pr.name }}');">{{ pr.name }}</a> |
{% endfor %}
```

this bars will be displayed in the html output, it is there to enhance readability. For example, if the providers list contains say `3` links in total they will be displayed one after another separated by `|` due to `for` loop.

possible output:

> |[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206870/what-does-the-vertical-bar-mean-in-flask-templates)|
>   [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206870/what-does-the-vertical-bar-mean-in-flask-templates)|
>   [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206870/what-does-the-vertical-bar-mean-in-flask-templates)|

Comment: Haha. This makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: my pleasure :) If it helps feel free to accept it as an answer.

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks again!